# How do I from convert from street level address to block/block group/census track?

Tags: data, census, united-states

I just downloaded block-level census data, using this answer [Where to get 2010 Census Block data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9380/where-to-get-2010-census-block-data)

It output a spreadsheet with a bunch of rows of the format

```
GEO.id                   | GEO.id2    | Geo.display-label
1000000US22071000100100  | 2.2071E+14 | Block 1002, Block Group 1, Census Tract 1, Orleans Parish, Louisiana
```

I want to convert "Block 1002, Block Group 1, Census Tract 1" to something like 700 Block of Jefferson St. Etc.

How do I convert these "addresses" into street addresses or longitudes/latitudes?

**Edit**

I can go individually from street address to census block using the advanced search on American Fact Finder, but I am looking for a way to do a batch conversion.

The FCC has an API that will do block conversions from lat/longitude to blocks: http://www.fcc.gov/developers/census-block-conversions-api

Comment: Didn't you download the features along with the data? The answers to the thread you reference describe how to do that.  The Census site itself gives plenty of instruction, too.

Comment: @whuber I did download the features but am not sure what to make of them. I don't know very much about the census. Can you link to the instructions?

Comment: Displaying features is *the* most basic operation in GIS, so consider running the tutorial for your GIS software. You can also [search our site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shapefile) for related ideas.

Comment: @whuber for sure. I am just learning how to do all this. When you say "The Census site itself gives plenty of instruction" can you point me where to look?

Comment: Wait a minute, do you mean FROM street address TO Census Block? As in enter a street address and return a Census Block ID as the result? Because that would make a lot more sense.

Comment: @Kotebiya Yeah. I am actually dealing with "block-level" addresses with the last 2 digits Xed out. So like: 4XX Juniper Street. But you are right that changing things around in the question title makes this more clear.

Comment: If you have ArcGIS 10.1, I would suggest this: ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2012_ADDLOCATOR/

Comment: Tiger files for a bunch of geographies usually ship with lat/longs out of the box (INTPTLAT and INTPTLON)--that was one of the things your were looking for ?

Answer (score 2):

If these are polygons, you can use the feature to point tool in ArcGIS.  Then use calculate geometry within the attribute table to create X and Y tables.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003m000000