# Census Block GEOid2 conversion to Latitude Longitude

Tags: census, latitude-longitude

My question is similar to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75870/how-do-i-from-convert-from-street-level-address-to-block-block-group-census-trac). I have two different data files.

```
Data1.csv (4500 rows)
GEOid                       GEOid2              Total Population    Urban   Rural
1000000US220019603001020    220019603001020     72                  0       72


Data2.csv (7000 rows)
Latitude    Longitude   ADT
30.48103    -92.61743   234
```

I want to get GEOid2 for each point (latitude, longitude) which I can do manually by using [this API](http://www.fcc.gov/developers/census-block-conversions-api). This task will be then tiresome.

Is there any particular method by which I can use the list of latitude and longitude to get exact GEOid2 for each location point by using that API?

Finally I want my table like this.

```
Data.csv
Latitude    Longitude   ADT GEOid2            Total Population   Urban  Rural
30.48103    -92.61743   234 220019603001020   72                 0      72
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Latitude and Longitude for each Census Block in Louisiana is available in the shapefile information for blocks in [these files](http://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2010/TABBLOCK/2010/). Download the counties representing your state, bring them together into one file, and then extract just the GEOID and the lat and long coordinates.

Note: Actually, assuming you only need them in county 22001, just download the blocks for that county.