# 2010 census population data by block groups for Florida

Tags: data, united-states, census

I would like to map population density by block group for the state of Florida, but I'm having a hard time trying to locate the correct data on the Census website.  I know I'll probably have to calculate the density myself, but I can't find just plain total population by census block groups.  I was going through the suggestions on this page, even though the question was about Census Blocks, but still not having luck:

[Where to get 2010 Census Block data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9380/where-to-get-2010-census-block-data)

Do I have to download each county's census block group data separately or am I just missing something?  Their website is very cumbersome.

I have the shapefile of the block groups just can't locate the 2010 census population data pertaining by block group so I can join it with the shapefile in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 2):

For the usual census website, I think you would have to download the block group population tables for each county separately.

But I found you can go to https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-data.html and they have TIGER/Line shapefiles already joined to population data at the block group level that you can download by state.