# 2000 Block Boundaries for an entire state

Tags: census, block

I am looking for 2000 census block boundary polygons for an entire state. Does anyone know where this might be available? I have looked at the TIGER/Line website from the US Census Bureau, but have only found 2010 block boundary definitions.

Comment: Better asked on https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @alphabetasoup Spatial data inquiries are permissible and encouraged on this site (e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/9380/8104)

Comment: If you say so; still it seems like the raison d'être of the other SE.